# Permission settings on SSH authorized_keys for user group

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, openssh, ssh-keys

I have several users who would like to access a `SSH server` via`public - private key` pair. I'd like to have a single private key distributed across all of them, and then have it matched with an `authorized_key` on the server side, which has the public key, and have a single key file on the system, rather than distributing it to every user profile and setting permissions on them individually.

I created a group of users, then used the `match group` and `AuthorizedKeysFile` directive within `sshd_config`to specify the location of the `authorized_keys` file, which should be used if anyone from this group of users is trying to log on. Unfortunately the key access does not work. I suspected it was because of permission settings, and sure enough, I see that I get a `permission denied` when SSH server tried to access that key file.

I gave the group read and write access to the `authorized_keys` file, but that did not seem to have solved the issue.

What permissions should be set on the `authorized_keys` file in the scenario described above, if it is indeed possible?

Comment: Only the user logging in can have write access to the `authorized_keys` file. So if you have the group write access, then it's the reason you cannot login (or one of the reasons). – Btw, your setup defies the very purpose of public key authentication.

Comment: I actually just solved it, by having the `authorized_keys` file in a separate folder, such as `/home/<somefolder>`. Group has `read` access to this folder, and the `authorized_keys` has `read-only` permission set on the file. Seems to work fine. However, I'd like to take note of your comment on the setup, may I know which part is specifically of concern, the one key-pair for a group, or having one `auth` file for the group, instead of having multiple copies in individual `$HOME` directories, or something else? I have some constraints like key sharing, because of which only 1 pair is available.

Comment: The one `auth` file was for my convenience, I can easily copy it to each user's home directory and set appropriate permissions. I'd like to improve this setup of course.